# Keep only first five rows if group has more than five rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with **USERID**(thus we group by this), and other variables **statuses** and a **date**.

Some of these **USERID's** have more than 5 statuses, so we should keep only the 5 most recent ones,by **date**.

How should I code this, looks simple but I haven't manage to do so.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: IMHO Please give new users asking their first questions the chance to improve their questions without downvoting immediately otherwise it is somehow frustrating and may drive away new users. Just my personal opinion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'USERID', we `order` the 'date' in decreasing (Assuming that the 'date' column is `Date` class) and get the first 5 rows with `head`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(-date), head(.SD, 5), by=USERID]
```

---

Or as @Symbolix mentioned in the comments, we could also make use of `.I` to get the row index and later remove the NA rows for groups that don't have 5 rows)

```
 na.omit(setDT(df1)[df1[order(-date), .I[1:5], by= USERID]$V1 ])
```

#### data

```
set.seed(49)
df1 <- data.frame(USERID= sample(LETTERS[1:3], 12, 
  replace=TRUE), date= sample(seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'), 
  length.out=12, by = '1 day')))
```

Comment: also `df1[df1[order(-date), .I[1:5], by=userid]$V1 ][!is.na(userid)]`

Comment: I think there is no need for the `if` statement (`head` delivers as many rows as available but not more than the limit)

Answer (score 2):

If you're a fan of `dplyr` you can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(USERID) %>%
  arrange(-date) %>%
  slice(1:5) %>%
  ungroup
```

On 'large' data sets the `data.table` approach will likely be faster, but `dplyr` has a slightly easier syntax to get your head around at first (in my opinion).